# Show that F(t) is an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry

I've got here an exercise that says: "Show that the map $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ defined by $F(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ is an immersion".
$F$ is an immersion if $dF_x:T_x\mathbb{R}\rightarrow T_{F(x)}\mathbb{R^2}$ is injective. Now $dF_x$ is $(-\sin x, \cos x)^t$ (am I wrong?) and it isn't injective, so it isn't an immersion.
Is it correct?

Comment: Fixing each $x$, $(-\sin x, \cos x)^t$ as a linear map is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for all $x \in \mathbb R$ $$\text{rank } (-\sin x,\cos x)^T=1 $$since $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ don't have common zeros.

Comment: Ok, I think I was a bit confused. So, every time I have to check if a map $F$ is an immersion I compute its Jacobi matrix, because $dF_p$ is represented by the Jacobi matrix, and check that its rank is equal to the number of columns. The same thing if I want to check if $F$ is a submersion, but this time I have to check that the rank of the Jacobi matrix is equal to the number of rows. Right?

Comment: @Claretta correct!